# CSS: Background-Image resize on ctrl + minus

Tags: html, css

Can you make a background image with this properties:

```
html,body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  background: url('../images/background.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover; 
}
```

to resize with the rest of the elements when you use CTRL and MINUS on your Browser. Currently when I am pressing the button the rest of the elements start to resize but the background-image doesn't do anything.

Anyone has idea how to make it re-sizable ?

Answer (score 0):

Your background image in the CSS is rendered independently of your HTML, and so it is difficult to grab a css background and apply rules to it through any type of scripting.

You can change this by instead putting your background in the html and manipulating it via JavaScript, or possibly through using a CSS preprocesser like SASS.

Here is a JavaScript work-around using a key listener.

You need to first take the input of the keyboard and store it in a variable:

```
var key = 0;
while (condition to check for keypresses...)
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 17) { //17 = ctrl
        alert('ctrl was pressed');
        key = key + 1; //key = 1 
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 173) { //173 = minus
        alert('minus was pressed');
        key = key + 1; //=2

    }
});
```

Once you have keyboard input working you need a function to resize your image:

```
function resizeBase64Img(base64, width, height) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $("<img/>").attr("src", "data:image/gif;base64," + base64).load(function() {
        context.scale(width/this.width,  height/this.height);
        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0); 
        deferred.resolve($("<img/>").attr("src", canvas.toDataURL()));               
    });
    return deferred.promise();    
}
```

Than you need to run that function:

```
if (key == 2) ...

resizeBase64Img(oldBase64, 100, 100).then(function(newImg){
    $("body").append(newImg);
});
```

remember to reset your key var to zero for new presses!

Here is a basic example of resizing images: http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/Sk7LA/1/
Key listener tutorial: http://blog.cnizz.com/2008/10/27/javascript-key-listener/
JavaScript keycodes: http://www.scripttheweb.com/js/ref/javascript-key-codes/

Answer (score 0):

Percentage values are not affected by browser zoom.

If you want your content to be proportionally scaled pressing ctrl +/-, you'll have to set its container width and height in px.

If you want a fullscreen background, you'll have to update your container dimensions in javascript on window resize.